# The minimum cardinal of a geometrical set

Tags: geometry, elementary-set-theory, contest-math, rational-numbers

> Let $S$ be a set of points in a plane $P$, having the following property: for any point $X \in P$ there is at least one point $M \in S$ so that the distance $|XM|$ is rational. Find the minimum cardinal of such a set.

---

First, let's notice there is such a set, by taking $S=P$. Also if $S$ is a line in $P$. Someone claimed there is finite set $S$ having the required property. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

UPDATE

A related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/362677/paper-punch-puzzle).

Comment: Why the set of points of a line having rational coordinates has the desired property?

Comment: @timon92 I don't have a prove, but I was told it is true because of the density of $\mathbb{Q}$ in  $\mathbb{R}$. Anyway, I remove it

Comment: The proposed duplicate is about removing all points with _irrational_ distances from one of the given points. That's a rather different problem.

Answer (score 1):

$S$ must have cardinality $\mathfrak c$.

The assumed property is that
$$ P = \bigcup_{(M,d)\in S\times\mathbb Q} \bigl\{ X\in P\bigm| |XM|=d \bigr\} $$
The sets in the union on the right are circles, and each circle intersects the $x$-axis in at most two points. Since the $x$-axis has $\mathfrak c$ points in it, it can only be totally within the union if there are at least $\mathfrak c$ circles. However if $S$ is infinite (and finitely many circles certainly won't cover the plane), then $|S\times\mathbb Q|=|S|\times\aleph_0 = |S|$, so $|S\times\mathbb Q|\ge\mathfrak c$ implies $|S|\ge\mathfrak c$.

On the other hand, there are only $\mathfrak c$ points that *can* be in $S$.

---

In particular, "the points of a line having rational coordinates" won't do -- there are too few of them. (Not to mention that some lines, such as $x+y=\sqrt2$, contain *no* points with rational coordinates).

Comment: OK, but what about S being all the points of rationale coordinates?

Comment: Also, the $P$ set looks maximal to me, or, at least doesn't look minimal

Comment: @EugenCovaci: (1) No, there are not enough points with rational coordinates. (2) I don't get what you mean by "$P$ looks maximal" -- it's your own letter that stands for the entire plane.